# Perform some task on windows shutdown in python Tkinter app

Tags: python, tkinter, ctypes, pywin32, win32gui

Imagine you are developing a Python application using Tkinter that performs different tasks on threads.
However, you also want to perform a necessary network call when the window operating system is
about to shut down. How would you approach this challenge ? I have so far used

```
atexit 
pywin32 api
ctypes
win32gui
signal
wmi
```

but nothing seemed to work. I have even tried to perform some operations on app's own closing event like writing a simple file

```
 self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", write_file)
```

but nothing performs on system shutdown.

Comment: There is a WM_ENDSESSION message, as the duplicate explains, but it doesn't get called in every circumstance.  Don't put anything mission-critical there.  Keep your app in a state where it can survive if things suddenly expired.